# What does s() mean?

Tags: python, bspline

I can not understand what `s(xx)` does in this code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.signal as sps
import scipy.interpolate as spi

# plot cubic cardinal B-spline (knots 0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
p = 3
xx = np.linspace(0, p+1, 100)
yy = sps.bspline(xx - (p+1)/2, p)
plt.plot(xx, yy)
plt.show()

# plot cubic non-uniform spline (m=5 DOFs)
xi = [0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11]
c = [2, -1, 1, 0, 1]
s = spi.BSpline(xi, c, p)
m = len(c)
xx = np.linspace(xi[p], xi[m])
yy = s(xx)
plt.plot(xx, yy)
plt.show()
```

I tried to just run `s(xx)` part to see what `s()` does, but it is throwing error `s()` is not defined, but when I execute the whole code, it works.

Comment: https://bsplines.org/scientific-programming-with-b-splines/

Answer (score 2):

Look, it comes from a few lines above:

```
s = spi.BSpline(xi, c, p)
```

`spi.BSpline` is returning a callable object as per the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.BSpline.html), that gets invoked like so:

```
s(xx)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is `s = spi.BSpline(xi, c, p)` in your program, that you have defined yourself. Nothing else specific exists in python for s.

Comment: See https://bsplines.org/scientific-programming-with-b-splines: 1) `s = spi.BSpline(xi, c, p)` constructs the spline s; then 2) `yy = s(xx)` evaluates the spline.  "s" *WILL* be undefined unless you initialize it with "s = spi.BSpline(xi, c, p)" first.